# How to change language of facebook interface in ipad2

Tags: ipad

I have ipad , I want to change language of facebook interface to Arabic 
I tried to change (Settings >> General >> Language & region >> Region) to Iraq and now its Iraq , then I uninstall facebook application and re-install again but interface still in English.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the page for that app in the App Store and you will see that Arabic is not on the list of supported languages.  So you cannot change it the way you want.